Smart Card MAC calculation on APDU for getting secure message
Here is my
Plain APDU : 00 A4 00 00

kSMac: 2F 34 E0 0D 1C 46 76 67 43 BA 6B 26 AB 20 4F D3

SSC:20 29 73 0A 6D 5E 7C C4

I am working on constructing a secure message and I am following an example and I am getting a wrong Mac value.
Here is what I have done:
 byte[] modifiedAPDU = new byte[] { 0x0C, 0xA4, 0x00, 0x00 };

//pad the APDU
byte[] paddedAPDU = Pad(modifiedAPDU);

//append Apdu to SSC
byte[] apduWithSSC = new byte[SSC.Length + paddedAPDU.Length];
Array.Copy(SSC, apduWithSSC, SSC.Length);
Array.Copy(paddedAPDU, 0, apduWithSSC, SSC.Length, paddedAPDU.Length);

//print the APDU with SSC
Console.WriteLine("APDU with SSC: " + BitConverter.ToString(apduWithSSC).Replace("-", ""));

byte[] mac = CalculateMac(apduWithSSC, kSMac);

CalculateMac()
static byte[] CalculateMac(byte[] data, byte[] key)
{
 // Initialize DES engine
 DesEngine desEngine = new DesEngine();

 // Initialize ISO9797Alg3Mac with DES engine, 64-bit block size, and ISO7816d4Padding
 ISO9797Alg3Mac mac = new ISO9797Alg3Mac(desEngine, 64, new ISO7816d4Padding());

 // Initialize with the key
 KeyParameter keyParameter = new KeyParameter(key);
 mac.Init(keyParameter);

 // Update with the data
 mac.BlockUpdate(data, 0, data.Length);

 // Compute MAC
 byte[] output = new byte[mac.GetMacSize()];
 mac.DoFinal(output, 0);

 return output;

}
Pad
static byte[] PadData(byte[] data)
{
   int blockSize = 8; // Block size for 3DES
   int paddingLength = blockSize - (data.Length % blockSize);
   byte[] paddedData = new byte[data.Length + paddingLength];
   Array.Copy(data, paddedData, data.Length);
   paddedData[data.Length] = 0x80; // Append 0x80
   for (int i = data.Length + 1; i < paddedData.Length; i++)
   {
       paddedData[i] = 0x00; // Append 0x00
   }
   return paddedData;
}

Expected Mac= A8 FB 97 D2 99 C8 05 2B, what could be the reason I not getting it - I am getting 15 D4 41 33 08 DF 54 86

What protocol? Secure messaging has not been standardized to such a point that it is well defined for smart cards. The MAC algorithm may be correct, but the protocol determines the required input.

Thank you - ISO/IEC 7816 standard. I am using Basic Access Control (BAC). I hope that answers the question. This is my first time to implement.

I'm starting to get rusty in this regard, but shouldn't you change the bits of the CLAss after calculating the MAC? You're also double padding, which I'm not sure is required for ISO CASE 1 APDU's.

I have update, when I run an apdu with data and I add DO 87 and DO 8E, I get the correct MAC! But one without data fails everytime

I did hint at padding only once, right? You're adding padding manually and automatically. Padding happens a bit strangely as the header always needs padding in this slightly dumb protocol, but if there is just the APDU header I don't think it needs another padding.

Malata, try to read work example for BAC from ICAO Doc 9303, part 11, Appendix D.
